matplotlib graph open : the tkinter variables are not correctly updated
In the program bellow, I open a graph with matplotlib (here in the example nothing appears, but anyway, the problem is not that). In the corner (left bottom), there is a button to add cursors to the graph. It opens a tkinter window to enter parameters (value cursor 1 on the x axe, and the same with cursor 2). When the checkbutton is activated, and the fields correctly filled (with float), it is supposed to create the cursors, and if th checkbutton is not selected, it is supposed to remove them. The problem is that the state of the checkbutton is always 'False', even when it is activated. Moreover, to get in real time the values of the fiels, I use the 'trace' method to trace the variable associated to each field, but it is always empty, even when something is inside. But strangely when I do saisie_curseur_1.get() (so get the widget instead of the variable associated, it works)
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog,messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.backend_bases import MouseButton
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.widgets import Button,CheckButtons,Slider,Cursor

def gestion_curseurs(event):
    global fenetre,fenetre_ouverte,largeur_fenetre,longueur_fenetre,bouton_curseurs,decision_curseurs,label_alerte_curseurs,saisie_curseur_1,variable_curseur_1,saisie_curseur_2,variable_curseur_2,bouton_valider_curseurs,bouton_annuler_curseurs
    if fenetre_ouverte=="non":
        fenetre=tk.Tk()
        fenetre.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",fermer_curseurs)
        fenetre.title("Gestion des curseurs")
        fenetre.resizable(width=False,height=False)
        fenetre["bg"]="black"
        fenetre_ouverte="oui"
        label_curseurs=Label(fenetre,text="GESTION DES CURSEURS",bg="black",fg="white",font=25)
        label_curseurs.place(x=0,y=0)
    
        decision_curseurs=tk.BooleanVar()
        bouton_curseurs=tk.Checkbutton(fenetre,text="Curseurs",bg="white",fg="black",font=25,variable=decision_curseurs,onvalue=True,offvalue=False)
        bouton_curseurs.place(x=0,y=label_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+25)
    
        if valeur_curseur_1=="":bouton_curseurs.select()
        label_alerte_curseurs=Label(fenetre,text="",bg="black",fg="red",font=25)
        label_curseur_1=Label(fenetre,text="Curseur 1 : ",bg="black",fg="blue",font=25)
        label_curseur_1.place(x=0,y=label_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+25+bouton_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+10)
    
        variable_curseur_1=tk.StringVar()
        saisie_curseur_1=tk.Entry(fenetre,textvariable=variable_curseur_1,bg="white",fg="black",insertbackground="black",font=25,width=10)
        saisie_curseur_1.place(x=label_curseur_1.winfo_reqwidth(),y=label_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+25+bouton_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+10)
        variable_curseur_1.trace("w",lambda name,index,mode,variable_curseur_1=variable_curseur_1:entree_saisie_curseurs(variable_curseur_1))
    
        label_curseur_2=Label(fenetre,text="Curseur 2 : ",bg="black",fg="red",font=25)
        label_curseur_2.place(x=0,y=label_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+25+bouton_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+10+label_curseur_1.winfo_reqheight()+5)
    
        variable_curseur_2=tk.StringVar()
        saisie_curseur_2=tk.Entry(fenetre,textvariable=variable_curseur_2,bg="white",fg="black",insertbackground="black",font=25,width=10)
        saisie_curseur_2.place(x=label_curseur_2.winfo_reqwidth(),y=label_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+25+bouton_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+10+label_curseur_1.winfo_reqheight()+5)
        variable_curseur_2.trace("w",lambda name,index,mode,variable_curseur_2=variable_curseur_2:entree_saisie_curseurs(variable_curseur_2))
    
        bouton_valider_curseurs=tk.Button(fenetre,text="\u2714 Valider",bg="white",fg="green",font=25,width=10,command=valider_curseurs,state="disable")
        bouton_valider_curseurs.place(x=0,y=label_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+25+bouton_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+10+label_curseur_1.winfo_reqheight()+5+label_curseur_2.winfo_reqheight()+25)
        bouton_annuler_curseurs=tk.Button(fenetre,text="\u2716 Annuler",bg="white",fg="red",font=25,width=10,command=fermer_curseurs)
        bouton_annuler_curseurs.place(x=bouton_valider_curseurs.winfo_reqwidth()+5,y=label_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+25+bouton_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+10+label_curseur_1.winfo_reqheight()+5+label_curseur_2.winfo_reqheight()+25)
        largeur_fenetre,longueur_fenetre=label_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+25+bouton_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()+10+label_curseur_1.winfo_reqheight()+5+label_curseur_2.winfo_reqheight()+25+bouton_valider_curseurs.winfo_reqheight(),int(fenetre.winfo_screenheight()/720*500*1.2*1.5)
        fenetre.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(longueur_fenetre,largeur_fenetre,fenetre.winfo_screenwidth()//2-(longueur_fenetre+2*(fenetre.winfo_rootx()-fenetre.winfo_x()))//2,fenetre.winfo_screenheight()//2-(largeur_fenetre+fenetre.winfo_rooty()-fenetre.winfo_y()+fenetre.winfo_rootx()-fenetre.winfo_x())//2))
    
        variable_curseur_1.set(valeur_curseur_1),variable_curseur_2.set(valeur_curseur_2)
    
        bouton_OK=tk.Button(fenetre,text="\u2714",bg="white",fg="green",command=entree_saisie_curseurs_bis)
        bouton_OK.place(x=longueur_fenetre-bouton_OK.winfo_reqwidth(),y=0)
    
def entree_saisie_curseurs(valeur_curseurs):entree_saisie_curseurs_bis()
def entree_saisie_curseurs_bis():
    print("curseur 1 : ",variable_curseur_1.get(),"curseur 2 : ",variable_curseur_2.get())
    print("curseur 1 : ",saisie_curseur_1.get(),"curseur 2 : ",saisie_curseur_2.get())
    print(decision_curseurs.get())

    if variable_curseur_1.get()!="":
        try:
            float(variable_curseur_1.get())
            erreur_curseur_1="non"
            saisie_curseur_1.configure(fg="black")
        except:
            erreur_curseur_1="oui"
            saisie_curseur_1.configure(fg="red")
    else:erreur_curseur_1="vide"
    if variable_curseur_2.get()!="":
        try:
            float(variable_curseur_2.get())
            erreur_curseur_2="non"
            saisie_curseur_2.configure(fg="black")
        except:
            erreur_curseur_2="oui"
            saisie_curseur_2.configure(fg="red")
    else:erreur_curseur_2="vide"
    if erreur_curseur_1=="oui" or erreur_curseur_2=="oui":
        label_alerte_curseurs.configure(text="\u26A0 Saisissez un nombre dans les champs en rouge.")
        label_alerte_curseurs.place(x=bouton_valider_curseurs.winfo_reqwidth()+5+bouton_annuler_curseurs.winfo_reqwidth()+10,y=largeur_fenetre-bouton_valider_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()/2-label_alerte_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()/2)
    elif erreur_curseur_1!="oui" and erreur_curseur_2=="vide" or erreur_curseur_1=="vide" and erreur_curseur_2!="oui":
        label_alerte_curseurs.configure(text="\u26A0 Veuillez remplir les champs relatifs aux curseurs.")
        label_alerte_curseurs.place(x=bouton_valider_curseurs.winfo_reqwidth()+5+bouton_annuler_curseurs.winfo_reqwidth()+10,y=largeur_fenetre-bouton_valider_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()/2-label_alerte_curseurs.winfo_reqheight()/2)
    else:label_alerte_curseurs.place_forget()
    if erreur_curseur_1=="non" and erreur_curseur_2=="non":bouton_valider_curseurs["state"]="normal"
    else:bouton_valider_curseurs["state"]="disable"

def valider_curseurs():
    global curseur_1,valeur_curseur_1,curseur_2,valeur_curseur_2
    if decision_curseurs.get()==False:
        valeur_curseur_1,valeur_curseur_2="",""
        try:curseur_1.remove(),curseur_2.remove()
        except:pass
    else:
        valeur_curseur_1,valeur_curseur_2=variable_curseur_1.get(),variable_curseur_2.get()
        curseur_1=ax1.axvline(x=variable_curseur_1.get(),color="blue",linestyle="-")
        curseur_2=ax1.axvline(x=variable_curseur_2.get(),color="red",linestyle="-")
    ax1.figure.canvas.draw()
    fermer_curseurs()

def fermer_curseurs():
    global fenetre_ouverte
    try:fenetre.destroy()
    except:pass
    fenetre_ouverte="non"

def REPRESENTATION_graphe():
    global     fenetre_ouverte,liste_points_signal,points_signal,x_coords,y_coords,fig,ax1,ax2,press,consigne,event_btn_press,event_btn_release,event_graphek,annot,on,off,valeur_curseur_1,valeur_curseur_2
fenetre_ouverte,valeur_curseur_1,valeur_curseur_2="non","",""

    x=[1,2,3,4,5]
    y=[1,2,3,4,5]

    # Construction fenêtres Matplotlib
    fig=Figure()
    ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

    axBtn=plt.axes([0.0,0.0,0.1,0.05])
    Btn=Button(axBtn,label="Curseurs",color="orange",hovercolor="yellow")
    Btn.on_clicked(gestion_curseurs)

    # Représentation spectrale
    ax.scatter(x,y,s=5,c="red")

    plt.show(block=True)

REPRESENTATION_graphe()

Why the variables associated to the fields and the checkbutton are not correctly returned ?

It is because the default backend of matplotlib is tkagg for your case, so the first plot window is actually an instance of Tk().  And the second window created by clicking the matplotlib button is also an instance of Tk().
The issue is caused by multiple instances of Tk() as those tkinter variables are created inside first instance of Tk() by default, so they are not linked to the checkbutton and entry widgets created in the second instance of Tk().
Either use Toplevel() for the second window, or set the master option of those tkinter variables to the second window, for example:
decision_currseurs = tk.BooleanVar(master=fenetre)


but know I have an other issue : when I want to plot my 2 cursors, I use 'ax1.figure.canvas.draw()' to display them. But they are not correctly displayed, at the wrong place : in the real program the graph comes to 0 to 1750, and when I plot the 2 cursors at 300 and 800, both of them stay close together at the point on the x axe around 0, it does not match the values choosen in the fields. Moreover, it makes the values of the x axe (the scale) disappeared

@Bast38 It is better to raise another question on the issue.
